# Managing selectors in functions and $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have functions that modify DOM elements on the page, but the `$(document).ready()` also access the same DOM elements, Do I wrap everything, including the functions in the `$(document).ready()` so I don't declare dom elements multiple times.  For example:

```
function addContent(){
   var $someElement = $("someElement");
   //Do something with $someElement
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $someElement = $("someElement");
   $someElement.click(function(){ //some code });
})
```

Would I move the `addContent()` function between the `$(document).ready()` so that I only have to declare `$someElement`  once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addContent()` only needs to be outside of the `$(document).ready(function(){})` if it is needed on the global scope. The same goes for the selector.

I personally wouldn't have either of them in the global scope if at all possible, meaning no `onclick=` attributes.

Comment: Actually, you can make it global by using `window.foo` instead of `var foo`. That's what I usually do, because when I use jQuery I wrap everthing in `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you do that, everything that calls the function has to be within `$(document).ready()`, so there's an upside and a downside. Up to you which is better. As Kevin B says, personally I'd probably rather them be hidden from outside that scope anyway, so I'd put them inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to use jquery with to the function use it outside the

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my impression that jquery started caching access to same saelector (at least it stopped complaining that we have to cache them ourselves) so it's fine to call $(".some") multiple times. On the other hand if you're inside a context of a class and you know that $(".some") will be always returning same set of objects - it's safe to store it in a class variable. And since global variables are evil - it's not a good idea to store it in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
// declared in global scope
var $someElement = null;

function addContent(){
   //Do something with $someElement
   $someElement.html('works!');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   //initialized on ready
   $someElement = $("someElement");
   $someElement.click(function(){ //some code });
});
```

you can make the variable globally scoped, and the initialize its value inside of `.ready`. Assuming `addContent` is always fired AFTER `.ready` fires, this will cause no problems, but this is a very safe assumption, because you intend to manipulate the dom with jQuery and that is always after `.ready`